# Erro ao fazer upload de foto

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tentei aplicar as instruções de fazer upload de fotos ao banco com [este artigo](http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/9062-upload-de-imagem-com-php-e-mysql).

Apenas adaptei para a extensão MySQLi. O código da conexão abaixo:

```
$conecta = new MySQLi = ("localhost", "root", "", "forum-ti-1");
```

Porém foram exibidos os erros que a figura abaixo mostra:

> Undefined variable erro in ... line 32
>
> Array to string conversion in ... line 38
>
> Undefined variable erro in ... line 45

Abaixo está o código:

```
<?php
include_once('conexao/conexao.php');


if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") and ($_POST["editar"])){

    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $data_nascimento = $_POST['data_nascimento'];


    if(!empty($foto["name"])){
        $largura = 1600;
        $altura = 1900;
        $tamanho = 500000;
        if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])){
       $error[1] = "Isso não é uma imagem.";
    }
        $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);
        if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
            $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";
        }
        if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
            $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";
        }
        if($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {
        $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";
        }
        //Linha 32
        if (count($error) == 0) {
            preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);
            $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
            $caminho_imagem = "photos/" . $nome_imagem;
            move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);
            //Linha 38
            $sql = $conecta->query("UPTADE usuario SET usuario.foto = '$foto', usuario.nome = '$nome', usuario.login = '$login', usuario.senha = '$senha', usuario.data_nascimento = '$data_nascimento' WHERE usuario.id = 4");


            if ($sql){
                header('location: index.php');
            }   
        }
        //Linha 45
        if (count($error) != 0) {
            foreach ($error as $erro) {
                echo $erro . "<br />";
            }
        } 
    }
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
                include('templates/header.html.php');
    ?>

            <?php

                $query_perfil = "SELECT nome, login, email, senha FROM usuario WHERE id = 4";

                $rs_perfil = $conecta->query($query_perfil);
                        while($lista_perfil = $rs_perfil->fetch_array()){

            ?>


                        <form class="form_profile_user" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="margin-top: 130px; margin-left: 330px;">
                            <h3>Alterar o Perfil</h3>
                                <label>Foto</label><br>
                                    <input type="file" name="foto"><br><br>
                                <label>Nome:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $lista_perfil['nome']; ?>"><br><br>
                                <label>Login:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo $lista_perfil['login']; ?>"><br><br>
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $lista_perfil['email']; ?>"><br><br>
                                <label>Senha:</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="senha" value="<?php echo $lista_perfil['senha']; ?>"><br><br>
                                <label>Data de Nascimento:</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="data_nascimento"><br><br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="editar">
                                <input type="submit" value="Cancelar" name="cancelar">
                        </form>

            <?php

                        }

            ?>

            <?php
                include('templates/footer.html.php');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

E abaixo está o formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
//Linha 32
if (count($error) == 0) {

//Linha 38
$sql = $conecta->query("UPTADE usuario SET usuario.foto = '$foto', usuario.nome = '$nome', usuario.login = '$login', usuario.senha = '$senha', usuario.data_nascimento = '$data_nascimento' WHERE usuario.id = 4");

//Linha 45
if (count($error) != 0) {
```

Comment: Indique quais são as linhas 32, 38 e 45

Answer (score 2):

> Array to string conversion in

Se objetivo é gravar o nome da imagem passa a variável quem o nome da imagem já modificado que é `$nome_imagem`, se for um blob use `file_get_content()` e jogue esse valor para o banco de dados.

```
$foto = $_FILES['foto'];

//código omitido
 $sql = $conecta->query("UPTADE usuario SET
                            usuario.foto = '$nome_imagem',
                            usuario.nome = '$nome',
                            usuario.login = '$login',
                            usuario.senha = '$senha',
                            usuario.data_nascimento = '$data_nascimento'
                          WHERE usuario.id = 4")
```

Para tratar o o undefined variable error, defina ela antes do primeiro if como um array vazio.

```
$error = array();
if(!empty($foto["name"])){
```

O erre acontece porque `$error` so é criada se entrar em algum if, caso isso não ocorra é avaliada como não criada/definida na linha abaixo.

```
if (count($error) == 0) {
```

Comment: Esta perfeito.. nao tinha visto o erro do nome da imagem

Answer (score 1):

Eu nao fiz o teste... entao posso estar enganado e tomar uns negativos.. mas acho que vc poderia declarar esta array error antes do primeiro if.. e em cada if vc pode usar o array_push.. provavelmente  isso resolve..

```
   $error = array();

    if(!empty($foto["name"])){
    $largura = 1600;
    $altura = 1900;
    $tamanho = 500000;
    if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/", $foto["type"])){
   array_push($error, "Isso não é uma imagem.");
}
    $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);
    if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
         array_push($error,"A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels");
    }
    if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
        array_push($error,"Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels");
    }
    if($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {
     array_push($error,"A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes");
    }
```